# Confused with the standard associative container set and vector

Tags: c++, dictionary, set

I am familiar with the standard libraries associative container map and the sequence container map. However I cant seem to understand the purpose of a set. While trying to understand std::set online I came across the following statement

> A set is an STL container that stores values and permits easy lookup.
>   For example, you might have a set of strings:

```
std::set<std::string> S;
```

> You can add a new element by writing

```
 S.insert("foo";.
```

> A set may not contain more than one element with the same key, so
>   insert won't add anything if S already contains the string "foo";
>   instead it just looks up the old element. The return value includes a
>   status code indicating whether or not the new element got inserted

So from the above text it seems to me like the set container only stores key and is not like a map which stores a key and a value. If this is true why is it an associative container and not a sequence container like a map ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really an associative container as it only stores values.  It has the property of a mathematical set that if you put the same value in more than once you still only get one instance of that. This can be very useful. Suppose you were trying to get a list of all the words in a document; a set would be great as they would occur many times in the text but you would just get one of each word in the set.

Answer (score 0):

You may think about it as an association of a key and a boolean value, telling whether the key is present in the set or not.